# Saving JULIA_NUM_THREADS with physical cores ot logical cores

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I need to initialize the environment variable to parallelize the solving of differential equations. I know how to create a system variable in windows, what I want to ask is with which number should I initialize this variable. I have 6 core CPUs but after including logical cores it becomes 12. So should I initialize it with 6 or 12 for better performance?
Also when I run the command `Base.Sys.CPU_THREADS`, I get 12 but when I run the command `Threads.nthreads()`, I get 1.

Also, like which one would be optimal, saving the `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` to 6 or 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always run Julia with the `--threads auto` option

```
julia --threads auto
```

You will see that it is allocating all available logical threads (case of my machine)

```
julia> Threads.nthreads()
8
```

Now the question "what is the optimal number of threads" is far more complicated. The rule of thumb is to use the number of logical cores up to around 16 threads. From my experience when you have a machine with a bigger level of parallelism multiprocessing is going to perform better (again depends on use case scenario).

In decisions like this `BenchmarkTools` is your biggest friend.

Another thing to be aware of is the hardware limitations - if you have laptop with 8 logical cores and you run it multi-threaded for longer periods of time it will overheat and you end up needing a new laptop (I have burned down three laptops this way).